# Change div text on resize of box (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm currently using jQuery to animate the resizing of a banner.
There's a div button that does this upon clicking.
What I'm trying to do is get the button to change its text from "hide banner" to "show banner" depending

```
<div id="banner_animate" class="banner">
    <div id="minimize" class="small_button">hide banner</div>
<script>

$("#minimize").click(function() {

  var new_height = 200;

  if ($("#banner_animate").height() == 200) new_height = 40;
  $("#banner_animate").animate({
    height: new_height + "px"
  }, 500 );

});

  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });

</script>
```

I'm pretty new to jQuery, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

in your `$("#minimize").click` you can use `$(this).text()`:

```
$("#minimize").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'hide banner') {
      $("#banner_animate").animate({height: "40px"}, 500);
      $(this).text('show banner');
    } else {
      $("#banner_animate").animate({height: "200px"}, 500);
      $(this).text('hide banner');
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#minimize").click(function () {

    var new_height = 200;

    if ($("#banner_animate").height() == 200) new_height = 40;

    $("#banner_animate").animate({
        height: new_height + "px"
    }, 500);

    $(this).text(function (_, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'Hide banner' ? 'Show banner' : 'Hide banner';
    });
});
```

Also, change the HTML to show banner at first like:

```
<div id="minimize" class="small_button">Show banner</div>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VksZJ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#minimize").click(function() {
    if($(this).html()=="hide banner"){
        $(this).html("show");
    }
    else {
         $(this).html("hide banner");
    }
  var new_height = 200;

  if ($("#banner_animate").height() == 200) new_height = 40;
  $("#banner_animate").animate({
    height: new_height + "px"
  }, 500 );

});

  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T9ypy/)